# Azcopy not working for a sas url that is working on browser

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, cloud-storage, signatures, azcopy

I am trying to copy a vhd from a sas url but that is throwing an error:

```
AzCopy /Source:"http://samplestorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/images?se=2015-09-30T00%3A00%3A00Z&sp=r&sv=2014-02-14&sr=c&sig=%2FjFBdrBBLMjByLqN7zSHyAKVWdc2bzuQvXGQ4j5r%2FhA%3D"
/Dest:https://destinatationstorage.blob.core.windows.net/images /Destkey:<DestKey> /Pattern:Sample.vhd /Y /Z:abcdef

Error parsing source location "http://samplestorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/images?se=2015-09-30T00%3A00%3A00Z&sp=r&sv=2014-02-14&sr=c&sig=%2FjFBdrBBLMjByLqN7zSHyAKVWdc2bzuQvXGQ4j5r%2FhA%3D":
The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. The specified resource does not exist.
```

But the same url when entered into a browser is able to download the vhd. I noticed one aspect with the sas url signature that the "sp=r" probably means it has read permissions. Sas urls that I could successfully copy have "sp=rl" which probably means it has both read and list permissions.

Is there a way of using Azcopy on urls that don't have list permissions? Or is the issue something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is the help of /SourceSAS option:

```
Specifies a Shared Access Signature with **READ** and **LIST** permissions for the source (if applicable).
```

Per AzCopy design, source SAS must has LIST permission。

For further information of AzCopy, please go to http://aka.ms/azcopy .